# I am getting an OS Error while running deepface. analyse function

Tags: deepface

I am running Deepface Analyze on images and getting below error, please assist.

OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 49623168, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 538771776)